# Pandas: Updating Column B value if A contains string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm looking to create/update a new column, 'dept' if the text in column
A contains a string. It's working without a forloop involved but when I try to iterate it is setting the default instead of the detected value.

Surely I shouldn't manually add the same line 171 times, I've scoured the internet and SO for possible hints and or solutions and can't seem to locate any good info.

Working Code:

```
df['dept'] = np.where(df.a.str.contains("PHYS"), "PHYS", "Unknown")
```

But when I try:

```
depts = ['PHYS', 'PSYCH']
for dept in depts:
    df['dept'] = np.where(df.a.str.contains(dept), dept, "Unknown")
    print(dept)
```

I get all "Unknowns" but properly prints out each dept. I've also tried to make sure dept is fed in as a string by explicitly stating `dept = str(dept)` to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any and all help. I feel like this is a simple issue that should be easily sorted but I'm experiencing a block.

Comment: you mean it sets all column to "Unkown" please? What you are trying to do seems to change the whole column instead of just one cell in the table. Please try to provide runnable example next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `str.extract`:

```
df['depth'] = df['a'].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(depts)})").fillna("Unknown")
```

Or:

```
df['depth'] = df['a'].str.extract('(' + '|'.join(depts) + ')').fillna("Unknown")
```

Both codes output:

```
>>> df
           a    depth
0  ewfefPHYS     PHYS
1  QWQiPSYCH    PSYCH
2      fwfew  Unknown
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

We usually do

```
df['dept'] = df.a.str.findall('|'.join(depts)).str[0]
```

Comment: But this would throw an error, for `Unknown` matches?

Comment: Oh! I though he has a cell that he is looking to change :/.

Comment: This is working for sure, and I thank you greatly. Do you know why the above for loop wasn't working though? I just want to understand the why behind it not working if that's okay. Thank you again!

It doesn't throw and error but returns NaN which I fixed by adding:
df['dept'] = df['dept'].fillna('Unknown')

Answer (score 1):

@U-12-Forward has a great solution if there is only supposed to be one new column entitled specifically with the string 'dept', not the value of each `dept` variable in the loop.

If the intent is to create a new column for each `dept` in `depts`, then remove the quotations around "dept" in the column indexer:

```
for dept in depts:
    df[dept] = np.where(df.a.str.contains(dept), dept, "Unknown")
```

---

The example is confusing because it is not clear whether there is supposed to be a new column for each `dept` (i.e, PHYS, PSYCH) because of the variable name.

This excerpt will not "work" because it would overwrite `df['dept']` on the second assignment with something that is only a combination of 'PSYCH' and 'Unknown' (there would be no 'PHYS').

```
df['dept'] = np.where(df.a.str.contains("PHYS"), "PHYS", "Unknown")
df['dept'] = np.where(df.a.str.contains("PSYCH"), "PSYCH", "Unknown")
```

What you are describing would certainly happen if there are no strings in column `a` that contain the final element in `depts` because the result of the last `np.where` would be all `False`, therefore return a full series of 'Unknown'.

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation! I see now where I went wrong. I was indeed trying to basically create one additional column with the extracted value from column a.